# PostgreSQL - Joining 3 tables subquery-key value pairs

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

Here is the db schema

Tables-

[image]

I want to write a query to search all files which have a metadata value like('abc')
and get a specific corresponding metadata value for that file.

So for above search for all files which have abc1 as one of the values and give me its corresponding 'geo' key's value.
I know it can be done by a subquery. But want to find the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could look like this. Should be the most efficient way, too.

```
SELECT m0.m_value
FROM   metadata m
JOIN   file_metadata fm ON fm.m_foreign_key = m.m_id
JOIN   file_metadata fm0 ON fm0.f_foreign_key = fm.f_foreign_key
--                      AND fm0.m_foreign_key <> fm.m_foreign_key
--  may or may not be necessary, depending on the selectivity of 'geo'
JOIN   metadata m0 ON m0.m_id = fm0.m_foreign_key
WHERE  m.m_value = 'abc1'
AND    m0.key = 'geo'
```

Be sure to assign aliases to multiple instances of the same table in one query.

For an overview of related query techniques see this lineup: [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879).

Comment: What do you mean by selectivity of 'geo'?

Comment: @Harpreet If `m_key` is not unique - in particular, if there can be a `m.m_key = 'geo'` - the commented clause would make a difference.

Comment: I don't think the 'techniques' (relational division, albeit in a simplified form) in the question are directly relevant here.

Comment: @onedaywhen: I think they perfectly are. This is another case of an n:m relationship (has-many-through), and the question specifically asks about different query styles and their efficiency. ("...subquery. But want to find the most efficient way.")

Comment: The answer by ypercube for that question is not a valid approach for this question. p.s. you didn't address my question there about the differences in performance not being significant. I have nothing further to add :)

Comment: @onedaywhen: I added the link here for a lineup of *related query techniques*. The *valid approach for this question* is **my answer above**. I did not answer over there, because I think you made a good point in your comment and I didn't have anything to add.